# Wordpress - white screen of death when trying to update a page and/or a file in Editor

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I'm loading a front-end site onto wordpress using a child theme of html5blank and I'm getting the white screen treatment - bizarrely (or not?) I'm only getting it when I hit the update button on a page or when I hit 'update file' from within Appearance>Editor.

I believe I've done all the standard checks - plugins, theme (why would I even get access if it was the theme?). I've looked on phpmyadmin and can't really see anything there.

This is what I have in my `functions.php` -

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'html5blank-style'; // This is 'html5blank-style' for the HTML 5 Blank theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

I've only just started the website build - I've only got Akismet and Hello Dolly in the plugin panel and neither of them are activated. Can anyone spot something in the functions.php that I can't see or is there other things I need to check?

Answer (score 1):

Having conducted a more in-depth search I found this [article](https://www.wpeka.com/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death.html) - and took the advice on hand by adding this code to my `wp-config.php` file -

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
```

This code points you towards the error on the white space, in my case it related to too much white space in my `functions.php` file. This [article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/fixing-cannot-modify-header-error/) helped me sort the issue out. All is now working as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple child theme with style.css and functions.php and you get a white screen for example if you update a post or try to change/load other themes during customization than you have to open your functions.php in your child theme directory. Remove all white spaces and all lines. It will work after that.

Child-theme with white screen error:

```
<?php 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

function theme_enqueue_styles() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('parent-style') );        //Comment with to much white space
}

?>
```

new child theme without errors

```
<?php 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('parent-style') );//Comment updated without space
}
?>
```

Btw: I have the second line because with first line I cannot overwrite the original style.css. Second line helps to do it without anything else.